# Why isn't my addEventListener working?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is the javascript. I can't seem to figure out why the addEventListener doesn't want to work. I try to mouseover, but it doesn't give an alert. This seems so simple, but I can't figure it out...:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CANVAS;
var CONTEXT;
function init() {
        CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas');
        CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext('2d');
        CANVAS.addEventListener('mouseover', poop, false);
    }

    function poop(e) {
        alert('This is an alert.');
    }

</script>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<canvas id="canvas" width = "256" height = "256"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you call `init()` anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What showdev said... you should call the init() function somewhere to have that code fire and add the event listener for you:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
```

Or you could call it in the javascript after you declare the function too, as long as you make sure it's called after your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

it works, only start init function, in body or at the end of your document 
http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/wapcs71s/

```
var CANVAS;
var CONTEXT;
function init() {
        CANVAS = document.getElementById('canvas');
        CONTEXT = CANVAS.getContext('2d');
        CANVAS.addEventListener('mouseover', poop, false);
    }

    function poop(e) {
        alert('This is an alert.');
    }
init()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't end the `init()` function and never called it. In your javascript, you could add

```
window.onload = init(); <!--> Add this line anywhere outside of other functions but delete this comment <-->
```

or in the `<body>` you could add

```
<body onload='init()'>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might have helped four years ago, back when it was originally asked, answered, and accepted.